# Could a moderator allow me to access a deleted post?

Tags: support

I posted a question on the math stack exchange a while back which has now become my only source of a set of notes I'd like to access. The only problem is, it seems I may have deleted it! Is there any way a moderator could allow me to access this post?

Comment: Try to look into the "[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/398608/daniel-castle?tab=questions)" section of your profile. Look for "deleted recent questions" at the bottom. If it is recent you could find it.

Comment: @ArcticChar It didn't come up unfortunately, I must have deleted it quite a while ago

Comment: May try [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1073325/deleted-posts-by-specified-user)

Comment: @ArcticChar It only returned titles for the posts I didn't delete, the rest are blank I think

Comment: If the while is not too long (90 days, iirc), you should be able to get at it via the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom of the "Questions" tab of your profile.

Comment: If you can somewhat narrow it down, especially a hint about the title and about when you asked it would make it  possible without too much effort.

Comment: one precaution can be adapted for your situation: keep an ordinary text file, then copy and paste the URL of any question you make, also the longer address when you gave an answer. Maybe work out a labeling scheme so you have an idea of the topic. Something along these lines has helped me a good deal finding older posts, mine or by others. I have a file I call Topics.txt , I have grouped links into a few dozen subjects. Much quicker to go through a single list on my home computer than search MSE. Oh, given a URL a moderator or 10K can view it for you